# Counting line intersections from lists in python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, zip

i'm just starting to learn python and I need to solve this problem but i'm stuck. We've been given a function (lSegInt)to find the intersections of lines. What I need to do is to format the data properly inorder to pass it through this function too find how many time two polylines intersect.

Here's the data:

```
pt1 = (1,1)
pt2 = (5,1)
pt3 = (5,5)
pt4 = (1,5)
pt5 = (2,2)
pt6 = (2,3)
pt7 = (4,6)
pt8 = (6,3)
pt9 = (3,1)
pt10 = (1,4)
pt11 = (3,6)
pt12 = (4,3)
pt13 = (7,4)
l5 = [[pt1, pt5, pt6, pt7, pt8, pt9]] 
l6 = [[pt10, pt11, pt12, pt13]]
```

Here's my code:

```
    def split(a):
      lines = []
      for i in range(len(a[0]) - 1):
         line = []
      for j in (i,i+1):
         line.append(a[0][j])
      lines.append(line)
      return lines
    sl5 = split(l5)
    sl6 = split(l6) + split(l6)
```

This is where i'm stuck. Need to find out how many times the polylines intersect. I wanted to use a zipped for loop with sl5 and sl6 but it wouldn't check every line of one list vs every line of another and the lists are different lengths.

```
while i < len(sl5):
    for x, in a,:
       z = 1
       fresults.append(lSegInt(x[0],x[1],sl6[0][0],sl6[1][0]))
       fresults.append(lSegInt(x[0],x[1],sl6[1][0],sl6[1][1]))
       fresults.append(lSegInt(x[0],x[1],sl6[2][0],sl6[2][1]))
       i = i + 1
print fresults
```

Function:

```
def lSegInt(s1, s2, t1, t2):
'''Function to check the intersection of two line segments. Returns 
None if no intersection, or a coordinate indicating the intersection.

An implementation from the NCGIA core curriculum. s1 and s2 are points 
(e.g.: 2-item tuples) marking the beginning and end of segment s. t1 
and t2 are points marking the beginning and end of segment t. Each point 
has an x and y coordinate: (1, 3). 
Variables are named following linear formula: y = a + bx.'''
if s1[0] != s2[0]:                # if s is not vertical
    b1 = (s2[1] - s1[1]) / float(s2[0] - s1[0])
    if t1[0] != t2[0]:             # if t is not vertical
        b2 = (t2[1] - t1[1]) / float(t2[0] - t1[0])
        a1 = s1[1] - (b1 * s1[0])
        a2 = t1[1] - (b2 * t1[0])
        if b1 == b2:                # if lines are parallel (slopes match)
            return(None)
        xi = -(a1-a2)/float(b1-b2)  # solve for intersection point
        yi = a1 + (b1 * xi)
    else:
        xi = t1[0]
        a1 = s1[1] - (b1 * s1[0])
        yi = a1 + (b1 * xi)
else:
    xi = s1[0]
    if t1[0] != t2[0]:            # if t is not vertical
        b2 = (t2[1] - t1[1]) / float(t2[0] - t1[0])
        a2 = t1[1] - (b2 * t1[0])
        yi = a2 + (b2 * xi)
    else:
        return(None)
# Here is the actual intersection test!
if (s1[0]-xi)*(xi-s2[0]) >= 0 and \
(s1[1]-yi)*(yi-s2[1]) >= 0 and \
(t1[0]-xi)*(xi-t2[0]) >= 0 and \
(t1[1]-yi)*(yi-t2[1]) >= 0:
    return((float(xi), float(yi)))  # Return the intersection point.
else:
    return(None)
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Sorry for the wall of text.

Comment: is the order important?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your `split` function is supposed to be used for, but I don't think you need it. I also don't know why your polylines are lists of lists, but here you go:

```
def count_intersections(polyline1, polyline2):
    intersections= 0

    # for each line in polyline1...
    iter1= iter(polyline1)
    point1= next(iter1)
    while True:
        try:
            point2= next(iter1)
        except StopIteration:
            break

        #...count the intersections with polyline2
        iter2= iter(polyline2)
        point3= next(iter2)
        while True:
            try:
                point4= next(iter2)
            except StopIteration:
                break

            if lSegInt(point1, point2, point3, point4):
                intersections+= 1

    return intersections

print count_intersections(l5[0], l6[0])
# this prints "2". I didn't manually confirm if it's correct, but it doesn't look too bad.
```

Not much to explain there: The idea is to count how often *any* line in polyline1 intersects *any* line in polyline2, so you simply need to iterate through both polylines and call the `lSegInt` function in each iteration.

Comment: Great, thank you! In addition to finding the number of intersections we also needed to find the locations of the intersections which is part of what the split function was used for. I did end up figuring it out a few hours after posting this. But, thank you anyways. Your answer will be helpful in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Make sure the lists are well configured. `x1` and `y1` are the points on the first line.  `x2` and `y2` are the points on second line.

```
def config_lists(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    line1 = list(zip(x1, y1))
    line2 = list(zip(x2, y2))
    return line1, line2

line1, line2 = config_lists(x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

2. Now that we have our lines, let's count the number of intersections. This only works if x values are aligned and if lists are same length. Also, most of the credit goes to OP, `lSegInt` does most of the work.

```
def lSegInt(s1, s2, t1, t2):
    '''Function to check the intersection of two line segments. Returns 
    None if no intersection, or a coordinate indicating the intersection.

    An implementation from the NCGIA core curriculum. s1 and s2 are points 
    (e.g.: 2-item tuples) marking the beginning and end of segment s. t1 
    and t2 are points marking the beginning and end of segment t. Each point 
    has an x and y coordinate: (1, 3). 
    Variables are named following linear formula: y = a + bx.'''
    if s1[0] != s2[0]:                # if s is not vertical
        b1 = (s2[1] - s1[1]) / float(s2[0] - s1[0])
        if t1[0] != t2[0]:             # if t is not vertical
            b2 = (t2[1] - t1[1]) / float(t2[0] - t1[0])
            a1 = s1[1] - (b1 * s1[0])
            a2 = t1[1] - (b2 * t1[0])
            if b1 == b2:                # if lines are parallel (slopes match)
                return(None)
            xi = -(a1-a2)/float(b1-b2)  # solve for intersection point
            yi = a1 + (b1 * xi)
        else:
            xi = t1[0]
            a1 = s1[1] - (b1 * s1[0])
            yi = a1 + (b1 * xi)
    else:
        xi = s1[0]
        if t1[0] != t2[0]:            # if t is not vertical
            b2 = (t2[1] - t1[1]) / float(t2[0] - t1[0])
            a2 = t1[1] - (b2 * t1[0])
            yi = a2 + (b2 * xi)
        else:
            return(None)
    # Here is the actual intersection test!
    if (s1[0]-xi)*(xi-s2[0]) >= 0 and \
    (s1[1]-yi)*(yi-s2[1]) >= 0 and \
    (t1[0]-xi)*(xi-t2[0]) >= 0 and \
    (t1[1]-yi)*(yi-t2[1]) >= 0:
        return((float(xi), float(yi)))  # Return the intersection point.
    else:
        return(None)


def count_intersections(line1, line2):
#     Make sure the x values of both lines are same length and aligned.
    assert len(line1) == len(line2)
    
    intersections= 0
    for i in range(len(line1) - 1):
#         Taking starting and end point of every segment in the line
        x1_start, y1_start = line1[i]
        x1_end, y1_end = line1[i + 1]
        x2_start, y2_start = line2[i]
        x2_end, y2_end = line2[i + 1]
        
        assert x1_start == x2_start and x1_end == x2_end
        
        if lSegInt([x1_start, y1_start], [x1_end, y1_end], [x2_start, y2_start], [x2_end, y2_end]):
            intersections+= 1

    return intersections

print(count_intersections(line1, line2))
```